# How databind a textarea component text value and update it?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, mvvm, vuejs2

I've been working on VueJS just 1 weeks ago for a project.

I've created two components:
* **Account.vue** (Parent)

```html
<!--It's just a little part of the code-->
 <e-textarea
    title="Informations complémentaires"
    @input="otherInformation" <!--otherInformation is a string variable which contains the text value-->
    :value="otherInformation"></e-textarea>
```

---

- **TextArea.vue** (Children Component)

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="e-textarea">{{ title }}</label>
    <textarea
      id="e-textarea"
      class="form-control"
      row="3"
      :value="value"
      v-on="listeners"
    >
    </textarea>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { FormGroupInput } from "@/components/NowUiKit";

export default {
  name: "e-textarea",
  components: {
    [FormGroupInput.name]: FormGroupInput
  },
  props: {
    title: String,
    value: String
  },
  computed: {
    listeners() {
      return {
        ...this.$listeners,
        input: this.updateValue
      };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(value) {
      this.$emit("input", value);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.components);
  }
};
</script>

<style src="@/assets/styles/css/input.css" />
```

When I write something in my TextArea Custom component from my Account.vue, my text value does not update and my listener function is not passed. Does I need to have something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily do this by **v-model**:

```
<textarea
  id="e-textarea"
  class="form-control"
  row="3"
 v-model="value"
>
</textarea>
```

it's equals to:

```
<textarea
  id="e-textarea"
  class="form-control"
  :value="value"
  @input="value = $event.target.value"> </textarea>
```

Comment: But now I've the following problem:
```html
```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"

found in

---> <ETextarea> at src/components/Custom/TextArea/TextArea.vue
       <Account> at src/views/Account.vue
         <Home> at src/App.vue
           <Root>

Comment: this is because you're using the data passing to the child component as v-model. it wrong because the child component can't change the prop data passing to it. Instead you can declare another data and use it as v-model

Comment: So I can declare a variable data in my child component directly, and modify it's value via v-model in the parent?

Comment: I've replaced the `v-on="listeners"`  in  my child component (TextAreaComponent) and now my function `updateValue(value)` is passed and my value is updated. But the updated text value is shown as `[object InputEvent]`

Comment: Nevermind I found the solution, by modifying `this.$emit("input", event.target.value)`

Answer (score 2):

Bind the value in your custom `textarea` and the `input` event:

`CustomTextarea.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="e-textarea">{{ title }}</label>
    <textarea
      id="e-textarea"
      class="form-control"
      row="3"
      v-bind:value="value"
      v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    >
    </textarea>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { FormGroupInput } from "@/components/NowUiKit";

export default {
  name: "e-textarea",
  components: {
    [FormGroupInput.name]: FormGroupInput
  },
  model: {
    prop: "textAreaVue"
  },
  props: {
    title: String,
    value: String
  },
  computed: {
    listenerFunction() {
      return {
        ...this.$listener,
        input: this.updateValue
      };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(value) {
      console.log("function has been passed");
      this.$emit("input", value);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.components);
  }
};
</script>

<style src="@/assets/styles/css/input.css" />
```

And use it with `v-model` :

```
<custom-textarea
    title="Informations complémentaires"
    v-model="otherInformation"></custom-textarea>
```

[More explanation here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: Hi,
I've did the modification, but still the text value from the custom TextArea does not update. Do I need to do something else? (I've seen the documentation)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully it will save someone some time. In Vue.js 3 they changed this a bit compared the Vue.js 2 and i got it working with this:

```
<textarea :value="modelValue"
          @input="onInput" />
```

and the onInput method looks like this:

```
onInput: function (e) {
   this.$emit("update:modelValue", e.target.value);
}
```

of course you have to have the prop 'modelValue' on your 'e-textarea' component instead of value as it was the case in vue 2.
i also added a watcher on this modelValue just in case it fails to update:

```
props: {
   modelValue: {
      type: String,
      default: null
   }
}
watch: {
   modelValue: function () {
      return this.modelValue;
   },
},
```

and yes, you use the component like so:

```
<e-textarea v-model="otherInformation" />
```

of course you can listen to the input event also if you want to, or need to for your specific case

you can also find more about this changes on
[here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#multiline-text)
and [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model)